# Command compatibility between Mifare Desfire & Desfire EV1

Tags: nfc, backwards-compatibility, mifare, apdu, contactless-smartcard

As you know MIFARE Desfire EV1 is the next generation of MIFARE Desfire with some features improving security.

Then is there any compatibility between commands used for communicating with Desfire & Desfire EV1? Does Desfire EV1 answer to APDU commands written for Desfire? Specifically consider security related commands (except AES related commands, as I know those were only added in Desfire EV1) and file access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, MIFARE DESFire EV1 supports all DESFire native commands from the previous version for backwards compatibility. This includes the security related and file access commands.

Comment: Unfortunately I cant vote you up because of lacking in my points,Then at first thanks a lot for edit & answer.Also I edited and extended my question,please keep me informed.

Comment: OK,I fixed this to it's initial state and ask a new question,WBR.

Comment: It is worth noting that applications using 3K3DES/AES crypto method are not compatible with legacy DESFire protocol when authentication is required.